# Using OPENDATASOURCE to query access stops the sql service

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I'm having trouble connecting to an Access Database through SQL.

When I try the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
                              'Data Source=C:\FitnessFirst\FF1.accdb')...Users
```

I get a transport level error, after which I find the sql service has been stopped and I have to restart it.

It really blows my mind that this query could actually stop the service, and that seems like a pretty huge bug to me because the ramifications of this in some production servers could be pretty severe.  Has anyone else run into this?

I know there are a lot of issues with connecting to an access database with a 64 bit version of sql.  I am running on a 64 bit processor, however the Windows operating system is only 32 bit so I wouldn't think that this should cause any issues.

Comment: Just for the record, I also tried creating a linked server and the results were exactly the same... it stops the server when I try to query a table.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Currently I'm trying on 2012 SP1.  Previous to writing this post I've also tried on 2008 R2 using both a 64 bit and 32 bit machine.

Comment: See if you get the same effect using OPENROWSET rather than OPENDATASOURCE.

Comment: @Rikalous For the moment I've just imported the data using the SSMS wizard so I can keep working but I'll let you know how that goes as soon as I get a chance to try it.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```
`EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1 ` 
`EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1`
```

I had the same problem and this worked.